# What environment_config for Beam launching flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am hoping for guidance on how to set `--environment_config` when running the Beam wordcount.py demo.

It runs fine with DirectRunner.  Flink's wordcount also runs fine (ie running Flink via `flink run`).

I would like to run Beam using the Flink runner using a "seperate Flink cluster" as described in the [beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/).  I can't use Docker, so I plan to use `--environment_type=PROCESS`.

I am using the following inside the python code to set environment_config:

```
  environment_config = dict()
  environment_config['os'] = platform.system().lower()
  environment_config['arch'] = platform.machine()
  environment_config['command'] = 'ls'
  ec = "--environment_config={}".format(json.dumps(environment_config))
```

Obviously the command is incorrect.  When I run this, Flink does receive and successfully process the `DataSource` sub-tasks.  It eventually time-outs on the `CHAIN MapPartition`s.

Could someone provide guidance (or links) as to how to set environment_config?  I am running Beam within a Singularity container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For environment_type=DOCKER, most everything's taken care of for you, but in process mode you have to do a lot of setup yourself. The command you're looking for is `sdks/python/container/build/target/launcher/linux_amd64/boot`. You will be required to have both that executable (which you can build from source using `./gradlew :sdks:python:container:build`) and a Python installation including Beam and other dependencies on all of your worker machines.

The best example I know of is here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/cbf8a900819c52940a0edd90f59bf6aec55c817a/sdks/python/test-suites/portable/py2/build.gradle#L146-L165

Comment: for others:  Please refer to this discussion:  https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/2cde8a1c2794c798a2509dda6a2bc3070a7f408e86a7c02376322c73@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E